# Reverse characters in a sentence

Tags: java, string, char

Im trying to reverse characters in a sentence without using the **split** function. Im really close but I am missing the final letter. Can some one please point me in the right direction? Right now it prints "This is a new sentence" as "sihT si a wen cnetnes" Also I included **if(start == 0)** because the program would skip the initial space character, but I don't understand why?

```
static String reverseLetters(String sentence)
    StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder("");
        int counter = 0;
        int start = 0;
        String word;

        for(int i = 0; i <= sentence.length()-1 ; i++ )
        {
            if(sentence.charAt(i)== ' '|| i == sentence.length()-1 )
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                sb.append(sentence.substring(start,i));
                if(start == 0)
                {
                start = i;
                word = sb.toString();
                reversed.append(reverseChar(word));
                reversed.append(' ');
                }
                else
                {
                    start = i;
                    word = sb.toString();
                    reversed.append(reverseChar(word));
                }
            }


  return reversed.toString();
        }

static String reverseChar (String word)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int idx = word.length()-1; idx >= 0; idx -- )
    {
        b.append(word.charAt(idx));
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: In cases like this, it can help to write down the sentence and run through the program by hand on paper.

Comment: I dont understand the if-else part. Too much duplicate code.

Comment: what is your expected result: the reverse of the full string or the reverse of each separate word? for the second case, maybe you can use a StringTokenizer, or create substrings between currentPosition and nextBlankSpace and reverse them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error lies in the index, the `for` should be

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= sentence.length() ; i++ )
```

Then `if` should be:

`if (sentence.charAt(i==0?0:i-1)== ' '|| i == sentence.length() )`

For me the error will be that the `substring(start,i)` for the last one `i` should be sentence.length instead of sentence.length-1, so this would solve it.

[Substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) is open in the last index, so if you put `substring(1, 10)` will be substring from 1 to 9. That might be the problem with last word.

The thing with the first space is also the problem with substring, let's say you're reading "this is..." the first time it will do a subtring with `start=0` and `i = 4` so you expect "this " but it really is "this". The next reading, with `start=4` and `i=7` will be " is".

So with the change of the index you should be able to remove the if/else with `start==0` too.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. What is this term called "i==0?0:i-1" Just want to read up about it.

Comment: You're welcome! That's Java inline conditional  or ternary operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java). It means: when i is 0, return 0, else return i-1. It avoids searching charAt(-1) in the first run.

Answer (score 4):

- `start` means `wordStart`. As i points to the space, the next wordStart should point after i.
- Hence the last `i` should point after the last word char, should be `length()`
- the if-then-else is too broad; a space has to be added in one case: i pointing at the space.

One could loop unconditionally, and on i == length() break in the middle of the loop code.

Answer (score 3):

Another option

```
private String reverse (String originalString) {
    StringBuilder reverseString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = originalString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseString.append(originalString.charAt(i));
    }
    return reverseString.toString();
}
```

Comment: the question appears to want to reverse the characters in each word only, not reverse the order of the words in the sentence.

Comment: yes, looking twice I think that you could be right @Kailua Bum, I got confused because I didn't realize that in "sihT si a wen cnetnes" there is an "e" missed to complete the reverse of "sentence" (I thought the reverse of each word was correct), so I thought that he was getting the reverse of each word but he wants the reverse of the complete string.

Comment: yeah its seems like the problem was getting that last char to print

Answer (score 3):

```
String reverseString = "This is a new sentence";
System.out.println(new StringBuffer(reverseString).reverse().toString());

Syso prints : ecnetnes wen a si sihT
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
i <= sentence.length()
```

In your for loop and change the if to:

```
if(i == sentence.length() || sentence.charAt(i)== ' ')
```

as

```
substring(start,i)
```

Returns the string up to i, not included.

Comment: i <= sentence.length() results in the String index being out of bounds

Comment: @DiarmuidCampion i<=sentence.length() will only throw an exception only if you call charAt(i), if you do like in accepted answer you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "This is a sentence";
        char[] charinput = input.toCharArray();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            stack.push(String.valueOf(charinput[i]));
        }
        StringBuilder StackPush = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
            StackPush.append(stack.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println(StackPush.toString());
    }
}
```

Not a split to be seen.